# unique random number generation

Tags: java

I'm looking for way to generate unique random numbers based on current time using java.
I'm a c++ programmer and in c++ I usually seed the Random with time so at each specific moment I can get a unique random number and it works like this :

```
sRand((time)Null);
x=Rand();
```

In java I found that I can use the same method by seeding the random number with time like this:

```
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Here is the problem I have used all the methods I found over the internet for generating a random number in java but none of them were truly random and they ranged from negative to positive numbers.
For example:

```
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int x=rand.nextInt(); // or long or float ...
```

What I get is a series of not truly random numbers and the result is really different than in C++.

I just want to know what the best way to do this in java is, some like or very close to TAC number generation.

Comment: What do you mean by "truly random"? Isn't it only possible to get pseudo-random numbers? As for negative numbers. You can pass an int as an argument to nextInt() so the results will range from 0 to n-1 (n being the value passed)

Comment: All software generated numbers cannot be truly random, at most they can be pseudorandom.

Comment: I want to make a random number based on each specific moment for example a unique random number at 4:04 pm. the generated number will change at 4:05 so it is based on time. I can do it in c++ but when I do it in java the number is not truly random sometimes the software generates the same number again

Comment: If they are truly random numbers, they will not be unique.   I believe what you are looking for is a GUID, which is quite a different thing.

Comment: A proper random number generator _should_ generate the same number multiple times.  If you want unique numbers, shuffle an array of numbers to choose from randomly, and return them in order.

Comment: @Louis , yeah your right but I said I seed it with time but I get the same result sometimes. I mean repeated numbers.

Comment: When I do it c++ I never get the same result.

Comment: I doubt that that is true.  You _should_ get the same result sometimes, if the random number generator is correctly implemented.  If that's not true in C++...then the C++ random number generator is not a very good one.

Comment: No the c++ way of doing this is just fine. I just wanna how to do the same thing in java. As I said I'm using the same technique but the result very different. I wanna get the same result which means no repeated numbers at all.

Comment: Anyway thanks a lot, I think I have to find another way.

Comment: ...I'm not sure you understand.  The C++ code, if the C++ random number generator is at _all_ properly implemented, _will_ give you the same results some of the time.  Not all of the time, but some of the time.  What gave you the idea that it returned unique values?

Comment: it only gives you the same number when you ask the program to generate a number at a specific time like 5:20:20pm. then the number will never be generated until the next day.

Comment: That's...probably not true.  What makes you think it's true?  That should be approximately as true for Java as for C++, depending on how long the time seed is and how much precision the clock is providing.

Comment: ok it works like this, imagine you add or multiply the random number with the current time. then at each specific moment a unique number will be generated. As far as I know this can be easily done by seeding the random with the current time but in java the program still keeps generating like a pattern and I get repeated numbers.

Comment: Are you reinitializing the random seed many times over the course of the Java program?  Can you provide a program that demonstrates the pattern?  Mind, you're seeding `Random` with 64 bits and getting a 32-bit value out; by the birthday paradox, if you generate 100000 random 32-bit values, you'll most likely see at least one duplicate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11777/discussion-between-louis-wasserman-and-loop-masters)

Comment: I found the problem, that was because apparently the program I wrote generates a long number and then cuts it into two half like what you just said. Thanks now it's fine now :)

Answer (score 8):

Java's and C++ random numbers are both [*pseudorandom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). Of course the algorithms are different, so the results are different too.

If you would like a random number generator that is strong enough to use for cryptography, you can use [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html): its interface is less intuitive, and it consumes more CPU, but the quality of its output is much higher than of a regular PRNG of Java,

Comment: I know about SecureRandom library but for some reason I don't want to use any library to do it.

Comment: I just wanna  know how to make that secure random myself.

Comment: This is almost certainly the worst thing you could do. `SecureRandom` is built into Java, and it is almost certainly better-designed than any random number generator that you, me, or almost anyone else on StackOverflow could write.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a *random number*, the simplest way is to use new Random().nextInt(), perhaps wrapping it in Math.abs() to avoid negatives.  If what you need is a *unique number*, you can use UUID.randomUUID().